# rEFInd boot macOS from Recovery HD fails. How do I get rEFind to boot MacOS recovery sucessfully?

Tags: startup, macos, recovery, efi

MacBook Pro (13" Mid 2012). Upgraded to macOS Sierra. Booting with <kbd>option</kbd> and selecting Recovery-10.12 works. Booting normally (turning the MacBook on and not pressing any keys), starts rEFind version 0.10.4.  Multiple icons appear. Selecting any icon works properly, except for the one with the label "boot Mac OS from Recovery HD". In this case booting starts and the Apple logo appears, the "load bar" indicates approxiametely 60% complete, and then the circle with a line appears.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Are you saying rEFInd boots at startup and provides a menu of icons to choose from. When you choose the icon representing the Recovery partition, this choice fails to boot?

Comment: refind boots properly and gives multiple options, all options function properly except for "boot Mac OS from Recovery HD".  In this case booting starts and the Apple logo appears, the "load bar" indicates approxiametely 60% complete, and then the circle with a line appears.

Comment: rEFInd version 0.10.4, when booted from a flash drive, does correctly boot a Sierra Recovery partition. The Mac used for the test does not use Core Storage. The flash drive was created from the USB flash drive image file that can be download from the web site: [The rEFInd Boot Manager:
Getting rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html).

Comment: @David Anderson - Thank you.  Good Idea, I installed  version 0.10.4 and no change. Boot Mac OS from Recovery HD dies with the crossed-out circle as previously described.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with a machine using el Capitan & Core storage.  Booting from a refind 0.10.4 USB, then selecting the small Recovery icon, does work.  Whereas refind installed onto the mac's internal HDD will not boot the recovery partition. Command-R no longer works either.